# regex for n characters or at least m characters

Tags: regex, character

This should be a pretty simple regex question but I couldn't find any answers anywhere. How would one make a regex, which matches on either ONLY 2 characters, or at least 4 characters. Here is my current method of doing it (ignore the regex itself, that's besides the point):

```
[A-Za-z0_9_]{2}|[A-Za-z0_9_]{4,}
```

However, this method takes twice the time (and is approximately 0.3s slower for me on a 400 line file), so I was wondering if there was a better way to do it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Optimize the beginning, and anchor it.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_]{2}(?:|[A-Za-z0-9_]{2,})$
```

(Also, you did say to ignore the regex itself, but I guessed you probably wanted `0-9`, not `0_9`)

**EDIT** Hm, I was sure I read that you want to match *lines*. Remove the anchors (`^$`) if you want to match inside the line as well. If you do match full lines only, anchors will speed you up (well, the front anchor `^` will, at least).

Comment: This works perfectly fine. And I only want to match the beginning of a line, so I'll just keep the ^.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution looks pretty good. As an alternative you can try smth like that:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_]{2}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]{2,})?
```

Btw, I think you want hyphen instead of underscore between `0` and `9`, don't you?

Comment: Yeah, I did mean to use a hyphen instead of an underscore between 0 and 9. BTW, what does the "?:" mean in your regex?

Comment: @david—`?:` means that the expression within the parenthesis is not captured. Check this site out if you don't know what I mean by that: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: @david, it's for non-capturing group as said above and it's more efficient then regular group.

Answer (score 3):

The solution you present is correct.

If you're trying to optimize the routine, and the number of matches strings matching 2 or more characters is much smaller than those that do not, consider accepting all strings of length 2 or greater, then tossing those if they're of length 3. This may boost performance by only checking the regex once, and the second call need not even be a regular expression; checking a string length is usually an extremely fast operation.

As always, you really need to run tests on real-world data to verify if this would give you a speed increase.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip. I'll try your method out. It sounds like a nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

so basically you want to match words of length either 2 or 2+2+N, N>=0

```
([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9][A0Za-z0-9])*)
```

working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<STDIN>)
{
    chomp;
    my @matches = ($_=~/([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9][A0Za-z0-9])*)/g);
    for my $m (@matches) {
        print "match: $m\n";
    }
}
```

input file:

```
cat in.txt
ab abc bcad a as asdfa
aboioioi i i abc bcad a as asdfa
```

output:

```
perl t.pl <in.txt
match: ab
match: ab
match: bcad
match: as
match: asdf
match: aboioioi
match: ab
match: bcad
match: as
match: asdf
```

Comment: -1, as A) it pains me to see duplicated expressions instead of `{n}`, and B) your solution only captures strings of even length (and even then doesn't do it particularly efficiently.)

Comment: A) no comment,  B) you've a sharp eye, thank you for noticing the error.