# Regular Expressions in R

Tags: regex, r

I found somewhat similar questions 
[R - Select string text between two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341402/r-select-string-text-between-two-values), [regex for n characters or at least m characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608760/regex-for-n-characters-or-at-least-m-characters),
but I'm still having trouble

say I have a string in r

```
testing_String <- "AK ADAK NAS PADK ADK 70454 51 53N 176 39W 4 X T 7"
```

And I need to be able to pull anything between the first element in the string that contains 2 characters (AK) and PADK,ADK. PADK and ADK will change in character but will always be 4 and 3 characters in length respectively.

So I would need to pull

```
ADAK NAS
```

I came up with this but its picking up everything from AK to ADK

```
^[A-Za-z0_9_]{2}(.*?) +[A-Za-z0_9_]{4}|[A-Za-z0_9_]{3,}
```

Comment: Is there a typo? Is the question "Take out everything between the first element of 2 chars and the string 'PADK ADK'"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this should do the trick:

```
\b[A-Z]{2}\s+(.+?)\s+[A-Z]{4}\s+[A-Z]{3}\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xD0mN4/2)

You'll have to switch the `perl = TRUE` option (to use a decent regex engine).

`\b` means *word boundary*. So this pattern looks for a match starting with a 2-letter word and ending with a 4 letter word followed by a 3 letter word. Your value will be in the first group.

Alternatively, you can write the following to avoid using the capturing group:

```
\b[A-Z]{2}\s+\K.+?(?=\s+[A-Z]{4}\s+[A-Z]{3}\b)
```

But I'd prefer the first method because it's easier to read.

Comment: Your code doesn't work in R, maybe there is something that must be escaped in a certain way.

Comment: @SabDeM I provided the raw regex pattern, you indeed have to escape the backshlashes with a second backslash: `"\\b[A-Z]{2}\\s+(.+?)\\s+[A-Z]{4}\\s+[A-Z]{3}\\b"` (I guess, I'm not familiar with R)

Answer (score 2):

Lookbehind is supported for perl=TRUE, so this regex will do what you want:

```
(?<=\w{2}\s).*?(?=\s+[^\s]{4}\s[^\s]{2})
```